# Unknown cause for difference in error between two html files with virtually the same codes

Tags: javascript, html, css, webgl

So besides the fact that there is actually an error, which I still need to figure out why, there is a difference in the error shown in the developer's tool console in Brackets editor and I'm not sure why.

The main.html file is the one that I made changes to based on the codes found here "view-source:http://learningwebgl.com/lessons/lesson01/index.html" (view-source needs to be included in the url), while the file main_copy.html is the actual codes that I copied and pasted from the link, and then backtracked through and added in my changes to see if I missed anything (thus the subtle differences in some warning strings).

Here are the two pictures showing the errors, the first one from running a Live Preview of main.html, and the second of main_copy.html:

[image: main.html error]

[image: main_copy.html error]

**HTML**

main.html

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Rubik's Cube Interactive</title>
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/canvas.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>

<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
</script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var gl;

    function initGL(canvas) {
        try {
            gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
            gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
            gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
        } catch (e) {}
        if (!gl) {
            alert("Unable to initialize WebGL.");
        }
    }

    function getShader(gl, id) {
        var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
        if (!shaderScript) {
            return null;
        }

        var str = "";
        var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
        while (k) {
            if (k.nodeType == 3) {
                str += k.textContent;
            }
            k = k.nextSibling;
        }

        var shader;
        if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
            shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
            shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER); 
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
        gl.compileShader(shader);

        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
            return null;
        }

        return shader;
    }

    var shaderProgram;

    function initShaders() {
        var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
        var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

        shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

        if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            alert("Unable to initialize shaders.");
        }

        gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

        shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

        shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
        shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
    }

    var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
    var pMatrix = mat4.create();

    function setMatrixUniforms() {
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
    }

    var triangleVertexPositionBuffer;

    function initBuffers() {
        triangleVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexPositionBuffer);
        var vertices = [
             0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  0.0
        ];
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        triangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
        triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 3;
    }

    function drawScene() {
        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        mat4.perspective(pMatrix, 45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0);

        mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

        mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, [-1.5, 0.0, -7.0]);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexPositionBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, triangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        setMatrixUniforms();
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
    }

    function webGLStart() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("project-canvas");
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        initGL(canvas);
        initShaders();
        initBuffers();

        gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

        drawScene();
    }
</script>

</head>

<body onload="webGLStart()">
    <canvas id="project-canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

main_copy.html

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Learning WebGL &mdash; lesson 1</title>
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/canvas.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>

<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
</script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var gl;

    function initGL(canvas) {
        try {
            gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
            gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
            gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
        } catch (e) {}
        if (!gl) {
            alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
        }
    }

    function getShader(gl, id) {
        var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
        if (!shaderScript) {
            return null;
        }

        var str = "";
        var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
        while (k) {
            if (k.nodeType == 3) {
                str += k.textContent;
            }
            k = k.nextSibling;
        }

        var shader;
        if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
            shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
            shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
        gl.compileShader(shader);

        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
            return null;
        }

        return shader;
    }

    var shaderProgram;

    function initShaders() {
        var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
        var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

        shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

        if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            alert("Could not initialise shaders");
        }

        gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

        shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

        shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
        shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
    }

    var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
    var pMatrix = mat4.create();

    function setMatrixUniforms() {
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
    }

    var triangleVertexPositionBuffer;

    function initBuffers() {
        triangleVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexPositionBuffer);
        var vertices = [
             0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  0.0
        ];
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        triangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
        triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 3;
    }

    function drawScene() {
        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        mat4.perspective(pMatrix, 45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0);

        mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

        mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, [-1.5, 0.0, -7.0]);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexPositionBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, triangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        setMatrixUniforms();
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
    }

    function webGLStart() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("lesson01-canvas");
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        initGL(canvas);
        initShaders();
        initBuffers();

        gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

        drawScene();
    }
</script>

</head>

<body onload="webGLStart()">
    <canvas id="lesson01-canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

canvas.css

```
* { /* Remove top and left whitespace */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body { /* Set to full screen */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

canvas { /* Remove scroll bars */
    display: block;
}
```

**JS**

gl-matrix-min.js can be found here https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/blob/master/dist/gl-matrix-min.js

Comment: the second error is unimportant (regarding favicon.ico) essentially there is no error in `main_copy.html` - when a browser loads a page, it automatically tries to load `/favicon.ico` - the fact that you don't have one, is not at all a problem - there must be some other difference in hosting or the path to gl-matrix-min.js (though, you should see an error with that as well)

Comment: What about the first error? I've been trying to look around the internet for some explanations and solution to that error, but I haven't found anything that made sense yet.

Comment: I posted a comment because I don't have an answer - knowing the second error isn't actually breaking anything means you need to look for less problems - how differently are the two files "hosted", and check the browser developer tools network tab to be sure all required files are actually loaded

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll check out the things you mentioned. Needed some leads.

Comment: I'm guess those errors are from one of your extensions. Try turning off all your extensions and see if it goes away. Also consider http://webglfundamentals.org 